# Attaching my query to a SQL transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

I've often run into this little problem when debugging my code. Let's say I have a C# application that processes a few SQL queries as part of a transaction. To keep it simple, I'll use the following example:

```
using (SqlTransaction myTransaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction("MyTransactionName"))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("first command text here", myConnection, myTransaction))
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Breakpoint here at which time I'd like to go check in SQL Management Studio what the state of play is

    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("second command text here", myConnection, myTransaction))
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So, as the code says, between the two SQL commands, I'd like to set a breakpoint in my code and check in SQL Management Studio what values have been affected in what tables. The problem is that I cannot run a query against the DB for as long as the transaction is still open. I have to wait in SSMSE for the transaction started in my code to commit or roll back before I can run any queries against the DB.

I've never really used or understood the purpose of giving transactions names (but I've never really used nested transactions either). But it got me wondering, if the name of the transaction is known, is there not a way in SSMSE to "attach" to an open transaction and then run some queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to set a breakpoint in my code and check in SQL Management Studio what values have been affected in what tables. The problem is that I cannot run a query against the DB for as long as the transaction is still open.

Use `(NOLOCK)` in the SSMS session to look past the lock:

```
select top 5 * from Posts with (nolock) where Score < 4
```

> I've never really used or understood the purpose of giving transactions names (but I've never really used nested transactions either).

Firstly, it makes working with intermediate save-points a lot easier, but those are rarely used. But a more important usage: it lets the DBA know who to come and kill when a transaction is blocking and causing problems.

> is there not a way in SSMSE to "attach" to an open transaction and then run some queries?

No, there is not; and besides, multiple concurrent SPIDs can use the same transaction name (you kinda expect them to, because usually the concurrent work is similar).

Comment: I love it when you learn three new things from a single answer :-)

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel here's a 4th, then: you can also use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` in SSMS, or (a 5th) you can configure this by default for new connections in Tools, Options, Query Execution, SQL Server, Advanced; or (a 6th) the current connection via Query, Query Options..., Execution, Advanced; setting this to uncommitted by default is a good way to avoid getting shouted at if you accidentally block your colleagues via SSMS; or, ahem, connect SSMS to a prod database (but we never do that, ahem, right?)